# Understanding a step in a solution that limits in a metric space are unique

Tags: metric-spaces, proof-explanation

I know how to prove that limits in a metric space are unique, but I'm trying to read an follow an alternative solutions from an instructor and I can't follow it. A paraphrase of his approach is as follows. The solution takes for granted the fact that a sequence $p_n \to p$ if and only if every open set $U$ containing $p$ contains $p_n$ for all but finitely many $n$. I'm bolding the sentence that gave me the most trouble.

> Let $p_n \to p,p'$ with $p \neq p'$. **Then for any $\epsilon > 0$, $B_{\epsilon} (p) \cap B_{\epsilon} (p')$ contains $p_n$ for all but finitely many $n$.** But if $\epsilon = \frac{d(p,p')}{2}$, then $B_{\epsilon} (p) \cap B_{\epsilon} (p') = \emptyset$, which is a contradiction.

I don't understand why the bolded sentence is true. An open ball is open, and an intersection of open sets is open, but the quoted result requires that the open set contain $p$; if that's satisfied, then it contains $p_n$ for all but finitely many $n$. But it isn't true in general that for every positive $\epsilon$, the intersection of open balls contains $p_n$ for all but finitely many $n$, as we just showed. It seems to me that I would need to know a-priori that this open set contains either $p$ or $p'$.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $p_n\to p$ and $B_{\epsilon} (p) $  is an open set containing $p$ , it must contain all but finitely many terms of $(p_n) $  and similarly $B_{\epsilon} (p') $

$B_{\epsilon} (p) $ contains all but finitely many terms of $ p_n$ means $\exists k_1\in\Bbb{N}$ such that $ 
 p_n\in B_{\epsilon} (p) , \forall n\ge k_1$

Again $B_{\epsilon} (p') $ contains all but finitely many terms of $ p_n$ . Hence $\exists k_2\in\Bbb{N}$ such that$ {p'}_n\in B_{\epsilon} (p') , \forall n\ge k_2$

Then $ p_n\in B_{\epsilon} (p) \cap B_{\epsilon} (p') ,\forall n\ge \max\{k_1, k_2\}$

Hence $ B_{\epsilon} (p) \cap B_{\epsilon} (p')$ contains all but finitely many terms of  $(p_n) $.